# PyMongo - can't connect to localhost?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have tried running the following:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client.test_database
collection = db.test_collection
collection.find_one()
```

but I get

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? I am running this behind a corporate proxy, but have already set environment variables for that in `.bashrc`.

EDIT

If I run `mongo` from the terminal, I get

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.13
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-10-16T10:30:23.269+0100 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: Do you have mongodb running on your machine i.e. localhost?

Comment: can you connect to the mongo with the cli?

Comment: @Reznik I've just added details about that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its look like you didn't run any mongo instance on your machine

run the command `mongod -f <config_file>` and then test it again (this may needs a `sudo` permissions)

Comment: Can confirm that I didn't have mongod running